# Django Rest Framework filter backend and filter class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have users endpoint working fine, with various FilterBackends. I'm trying to add in a new filter to be able to pass in a list of ids such as `?ids=1,5,7` and returning only those users.

I have found the following filter which accomplishes that, but then breaks my other filters:

```
class ListFilter(Filter):
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if not value:
            return qs

        self.lookup_type = 'in'
        values = value.split(',')
        return super(ListFilter, self).filter(qs, values)


class UserListFilter(FilterSet):
    ids = ListFilter(name='id')

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['ids']


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter, InterestsFilter)
    filter_fields = ('username', 'native_language', 'country', 'interests',)
    ordering_fields = ('username',)
    search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name')
    filter_class = UserListFilter
```

Before adding in this custom filter_class, all the filter backends work fine, but then after adding in the filter_class, it breaks them all, but I can then filter by a list of ids.

In the [filtering docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/) they give an example using both backends and filter, so I would think this should work, but it's something wrong with my code. Any ideas?

Comment: I had a similar issue when tried to mix filter_backends with filter_class. But then I found that django-filter has also a capability of ordering results and this is what I needed, so I just defined ordering filter using django-filter and stopped using filter_backends on that class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the `get_queryset` method and achieve the functionality of filtering by `ids`.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    ids = self.request.query_params.get('ids') # List of ids
    if ids:
        return User.objects.all().filter(id__in=ids) # returned queryset filtered by ids
    return User.objects.all() # return whole queryset
```

Comment: thanks! That's much cleaner. 'ids[]' didn't work for me btw django 1.8 drf 3.1.2, needed to change to 'ids' and then split the string